# How to: Rxjs Observable Process values in order (concatMap), handling errors(catchError), without 'stopping' (switchmap)

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, rxjs-observables, switchmap, concatmap

**Goal:** Process(async Call) all elements from Observable **in order, finishing one before the next** (concatMap style) while handling errors from bad elements without stopping.

It is understood that an observable that errors, will stop its emissions
As per this question:
[rxjs error handling > on catchError source stops emitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743528/rxjs-error-handling-on-catcherror-source-stops-emitting)

1. One solution might be - to extend the above solution, to include the sequenced processing of concatMap - Not sure how this would be done?
2. Another solution - add a switchMap and Observable to my Demo?
   The StackBlitz below is as far as I managed. It Demonstrates the desired behavior, but lacks a true source observable, that is 'error protected' - to keep it from stopping.
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8akf2h?file=index.ts

Any help to establish the stated goal would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you add catch handler function out of concatMap, like this:

```
outer$.pipe(
  concatMap((a) => return whatever(errorHandler)),
  catchError()
)
```

Once inner stream throws an error, stream will end.

But if you add catchError() like this:

```
outer$.pipe(
  concatMap((a) => return whatever().pipe(catchError(errorHandler)))
)
```

It will continue, ofc you have to handle errors correctly in catch handler.

Comment: Simple - make sure you never raise from the concat. No need to switchMap - Thank you.